# Is it possible to make Firefox open a folder of bookmarks in a new window?

Tags: windows, firefox, browser-tabs

Is it possible to make Firefox open an entire folder of bookmarks in a new window?  Each bookmark in the folder would have its own tab in the new window.  I know about middle-clicking to open a folder of bookmarks all at once, but as far as I can tell, that always creates the new tabs in the current window.

I know I could just open a new window and then open all the tabs, but a one-step process would just be *that* much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Shift+Click on the folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work anymore. Firefox 51 will open the bookmarks in tabs in the current window.

Comment: Still works for me on FF 51.0.1, while pressing Alt closes the bookmarks dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

In the current Firefox release (tested in 51.0.1), use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click.